# Preview new changes in frontend of website with index.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, xampp

I've desperately tried to make my index.php to show me the preview of the changes I made on my website, before uploading it online. But after doing all the necessary steps I still cannot get hold of it. [image: My HTDOCS]

[image: This is the error]

I've taken following necessary steps:

1. I have downloaded XAMPP control panel.
2. Put all the necessary files in my HTDOCS.
3. Started all the modules (Apache, MySQL, FileZilla, Mercury, Tomcat).
4. Searched for http://localhost/index.php in Google Chrome.

This is the error I get:

> An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If
>   this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/system/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysql.php [61]:
>   mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed
>   in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Any idea what can be causing it?

Comment: Well, don't use the `mysql` extension.  It's deprecated.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

mysql library is deprecated now in new PHP versions, due to security issues. So you should use mysqli or PDO in your project.

Comment: OK. 
So i guess I will be needing some kind of mysqli database driver to put in the database folder and edit my config.php (in root directory) to define('DB_DRIVER', 'mmysqli');?
Is that all?

Comment: Not actually. http://php.net/mysqli As you can see, only difference is it works like curl, so you should only update your codes.

Comment: mysqli and PDO are packed into PHP on most servers (and most definitely solutions like XAMPP). mysql extension has been deprecated for long, but only recently been actively tried to push out of the PHP system... Go read some docs and examples on how to use them. They're somewhat different...